# Grabbing only one ( newest ) detail record from child table for multiple parent Id's in one query

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have problem with one query and to be honest i have no idea if this is even possible to write in good and readable way.

I have 2 table.

First is Event with 4 columns :

```
EVENT_ID | EVENT_TYPE | DETAIL_TYPE | DETAIL_ID
```

Second table is EVENT_DETAIL with more than 10 columns but we need only 3 of them:

```
DETAIL_ID | ..... | TIME | DESCRIPTION.
```

In current scenario we are storing Events in EVENT table. Each event can have multiple details with multiple types.

What i need to do is grab description DESCRIPTION for EVENT_ID that have latest EVENT_DETAIL.TIME

I created this SQL and maybe it is not good looking but at least it work:

```
SELECT * FROM EVENT_DETAIL ED
WHERE ED.DESCRIPTION IN
(SELECT * FROM
( SELECT ED.DESCRIPTION
FROM EVENT_DETAIL ED
JOIN EVENT E ON ED.DETAIL_ID = E.DETAIL_ID AND 
E.EVENT_ID = 10 AND E.EVENT_TYPE  = 1 AND  E.DETAIL_TYPE = 1
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY ED.TIME DESC));
```

Problem is that in that `SQL` i can pass only one EVENT_ID ( i know that i can join it multiple times but I don't think that this will be good idea )  and i need to run this query for for example ten EVENT's (EVENT_TYPE and DETAIL_TYPE will be same for whole time ).

In current product i have solution in C# code. Fist I Grab all DETAILS_ID for Each EVENT and then calling another `SQL` to grab all details for this id and sorting it by use `LINQ` garbing latest. Technically this work but is very slow.

So my question is can I have one SQL statement to grab latest DESCRIPTION for each EVENT_ID that I pass ( EVENT_TYPE and DETAIL_TYPE will be same for each EVENT_ID) ?

So for data like :

EVENTS :

```
10    |    1    |    1    |    1
10    |    1    |    1    |    2
10    |    1    |    1    |    3
11    |    1    |    1    |    5
11    |    1    |    1    |    6
11    |    1    |    1    |    7
```

EVENT_DETAIL:

```
1     |    12-12-2013    |    TEST1    
2     |    12-13-2013    |    TEST2    
3     |    12-14-2013    |    TEST3      
5     |    12-13-2013    |    TEST4    
6     |    12-14-2013    |    TEST5   
7     |    12-15-2013    |    TEST6
```

And parameters `EVENT_ID in (10,11) , EVENT_TYPE = 1 , DETAIL_TYPE = 1`

I want to have results like :

```
3    |    TEST3
7    |    TEST6
```

Thanks.

Comment: I just want to understand, you have Multiple EVENTS. Each EVENT can have mulitple EVENT_DETAILS. You want to pass one query that grabs the most recent EVENT_DETAILS for an EVENT?

Comment: I want to pass one query to grab only latest ( sorted by time ) EVENT_DETAIL for each EVENT. I will edit by question to explain this.

Comment: Questions is fine, I miss typed my question. I edited it, but you didn't see it in time sorry.

Comment: Why doesn't `EVENT_DETAIL` have `EVENT_ID`?  I can't follow the data structure.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I edited my question with sample data.

Comment: This will return all rows unless u hard code event_detailID `3,7`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join with the max(ed.time) group by detail_id

```
select * from 
FROM EVENT_DETAIL ED 
inner join (
      select ED.DETAIL_ID,   max(ED.TIME) max_time
      FROM EVENT_DETAIL ED
      JOIN EVENT E ON ED.DETAIL_ID = E.DETAIL_ID 
      group by ED.DESCRIPTION 
) T.DETAIL_ID = ED.DETAIL_ID  AND ED.TIME = T.max_time
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because i think `DETAIL_ID` is unique on each row in `EVENT_DETAIL`.  Hard to say, because the data structure is rather arcane, but this is my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use window function to get the most recent detail of each type for an event:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ED.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.EVENT_ID, E.DETAIL_TYPE ORDER BY ED.TIME DESC) as seqnum
      FROM EVENT_DETAIL ED JOIN
           EVENT E
           ON ED.DETAIL_ID = E.DETAIL_ID
     ) ED
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a windowing function for this purpose. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
select EVENT_ID, 
       DESCRIPTION
from (  
    select E.EVENT_ID, 
           ED.DESCRIPTION,
           row_number() over (partition by DETAIL_ID order by TIME desc) as rnum
    from EVENT E
    join EVENT_DETAIL ED 
    on (ED.DETAIL_ID = E.DETAIL_ID)) t
where t.rnum = 1
```